Blazor application can not run at offline specfically in firefox browser
I had devlop the blazorWASM application with indexedDb. I had implement service worker for offline application WIth PWA also. Offline working successfully in chrome and edge browser but firefox not working i got the error while debugging that error is
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable
InvalidStateError realted indexeddb. Indexeddb object not properly intalized at offline i think thats why when saw the indexedb on browser that is not created
Service worker runing when application open then after serve caches resources to client service worker stopped. when i was try to run application offline i got the InvalidStateError message
please help me. thanks
I had used blazorindexedb package for deveop the application
https://github.com/nwestfall/BlazorDB
Service worker runing when application open then after serve caches resources to client service worker stopped. when i was try to run application offline i got the InvalidStateError message
